# odfWeave for Google Docs

Tags: r, google-docs

Is it possible to integrate odfWeave with Google Docs?  Specifically, does one have to:

1. Create the document in R, then import to GD, or
2. Create it in GD and then import to R?

The specific usage case is to share weaved documents with collaborators who don't know LaTeX (and please don't say just find different collaborators--not possible!).

I see two challenges:

1. Google Docs might destroy any embedded metadata that odfWeave places in, and
2. Document synching might be difficult (but the `RGoogleDocs` package would make this considerably easier)

Has anyone made any progress in resolving these challenges?